# Convert ogg audio to wav in python without ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, python, ffmpeg

I am getting oga file from javascript blob and I want to convert it to PCM compatible wav file in python.
The approach I am using is as follow

```
AudioSegment.converter = r"C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"
AudioSegment.ffprobe   = r"C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe"
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("file.oga")
sound.export("file.wav", format="wav")
```

For this I have to download ffmpeg locally.
Is there any way to convert oga file to wave directly.

This is how i am saving file

```
f = open('./file.oga', 'wb')
f.write(base64.b64decode(file))
f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

pydub is your friend!

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

def ogg2wav(ofn):
    wfn = ofn.replace('.ogg','.wav')
    x = AudioSegment.from_file(ofn)
    x.export(wfn, format='wav')    # maybe use original resolution to make smaller
```

Comment: FYI, pydub requires ffmpeg or avconf